Have children's car seats not been proven to be more effective than seat belts alone for kids older than 24 months?
A comment on a question on the Travel Stack Exchange claims that "child seats [in cars] have never been proven to be more effective than seat belts for kids older than 24 months", and links to a Freakonomics article published in the New York Times (archive link). That article summarises an analysis of data from the Fatality Analysis Reporting System (FARS) as follows: "there is no evidence that car seats do a better job than seat belts in saving the lives of children older than 2". The article does not describe the actual analysis conducted in much detail, and does not cite any other studies on the subject.
A Google Scholar search does not find recent articles that investigate this question, research seems to be focused on measuring prevalence of child seat use, effectiveness of training programs on child seat use, or correctness of child seat use. Is there evidence to support or refute the argument made in the Freakonomics article?

The archive link shows a blank page, but presumably by 'car seats' they mean 'child seats'. And it isn't either/or: child seats are used in conjunction with seat belts, so that the belt doesn't throttle the child. A young child can only use the lap part of the belt, which they can easily slip underneath. With a seat for a young child (not just a booster for older children), there is a separate harness for the child, and the normal seat belt secure it all.

@WeatherVane: Thanks for the note about the blank archive link (strangely it works for me). I added a link to the live version of the New York Times article (paywalled) in addition to the archive version. The article argues that for children over 2 years of age properly used child seats (with the corresponding restraint system) are just as effective as properly used seat belts without a child seat or booster.

I note that the article says "More information on the academic research behind this column [...] is at www.freakonomics.com", so while they don't include the details they include some breadcrumbs.

...where a search brings up two snippets from 2005. "If you were watching the Today Show, you saw Dubner talking about car seats vs. seat belts," and "…or incapacitating injuries for children in car seats versus children using adult seat belts" which smells like the original anti-seatbelt argument.

@WeatherVane That might be a language thing. In US English, it's common to call child safety seats just "car seats" and the term "child seats" isn't regularly used for this. If I google "car seat," every result is some sort of safety seat for children. We would also call the entire seat assembly that comes with the car a "car seat," but people don't usually need to shop for those on their own, and it's usually clear from context whether someone is talking about a factory-installed car seat or a child safety seat when they say "car seat."

@ZachLipton This is the same as in the UK, so I’m not sure of WeatherVane’s confusion (who is in the UK, according to their profile).

Thanks for posting this but I do wish this question focused on dummy test crash data vs. other sources of inferring the answer. Unfortunately (as far as I know) only Levitt et al. have conducted such a test.

There is evidence otherwise
The second author of the NYT article is Steven D. Levitt, who also wrote Evidence that Seat Belts are as Effective as Child Safety Seats in Preventing Death for Children Aged Two and Up, published in the peer-reviewed journal The Review of Economics and Statistics. From the abstract:

Using data from the Fatality Analysis Reporting System (FARS) on all fatal crashes in the United States from 1975-2003, I find that child safety seats, in actual practice, are no better than seat belts at reducing fatalities among children aged 2-6. This result is robust to a wide range of sensitivity analyses, including controlling for sample selection that arises because the FARS data set includes only crashes in which at least one fatality occurs.

While the NYT article makes its own conclusions regarding risk of injuries, the study did not even attempt to research that, nor could it with the dataset. Digging deeper, I found a paper (Effectiveness of Child Safety Seats vs Safety Belts for Children Aged 2 to 3 Years) citing that one which explains a lot more:

[Levitt's] work is out of step with the literature. It contrasts with the literature establishing the effectiveness of child safety seats relative to unrestrained travel. More important, subsequent analysis by Elliott et al found that child restraints for children aged 2 through 6 years, when not seriously misused, reduce the risk of death by 28% compared with seat belts. Prior studies also found that child safety seats were more effective against fatalities than safety belts. Relative to unrestrained travel, child safety seat restraints reduced the risk of death by an estimated 47% for toddlers aged 1 to 4 years. At most, though, for this age group, they offered a modest fatality risk reduction vs safety belts, which were estimated to be 45% effective against deaths among people 12 years and older and 36.5% to 39% effective for toddlers.
The analyses by Levitt and Dubner and Levitt have 3 major limitations. First, it included children up to the age of 6 years, meaning it confounded seat effectiveness for children of appropriate weight and stature for a child seat and larger children whose restraint in a child seat constitutes misuse. Second, it used a fatal crash data file that lacked a good control variable for crash severity. Third, it largely restricted its analysis to fatalities, with some glancing attention to nonfatal injuries coded by police using a coarse inaccurate severity measurement system. Fully analyzing the appropriateness of child safety seat laws for toddlers, however, also requires considering the relative impacts of child safety seats and lap-shoulder belts against nonfatal injury. A few studies have examined the effects on nonfatal injuries to specific body regions (eg, severe abdominal injuries) but not on total injuries. Only 2 studies used a design similar to that used by Levitt and coworker to analyze effects on nonfatal injury. One limited the analysis to significant injuries, which were defined as an Abbreviated Injury Scale (AIS) score of 2 or more. Neither distinguished lap-shoulder from lap-only belts. One found that children aged 2 to 5 years in seat belts had a 3.5 times higher relative risk of significant injuries than those in child restraint systems. The other found an odds ratio of 0.22 (95% confidence interval, 0.11-0.45) of significant injury in a child seat vs a safety belt, but found no difference in the odds of minor injury. Our study covers all nonfatal injuries and, like the work by Levitt and coworker, it specifically examines lap-shoulder belts. It addresses the probability of being injured, analyzes crashes that resulted in at least 1 vehicle being towed away, and is restricted to passenger vehicles with occupants aged 2 to 3 years.

As the title would indicate, the injury angle is the main focus of that newer paper, which examined data on toddlers (ages 2–3) who were in accidents where at least one car had to be towed, over the years 1998–2004 in the US. Its summary:

The adjusted odds of injury were 81.8% lower (95% confidence interval, 58.3%-92.1% lower) for toddlers in child seats than belted toddlers.


Using only fatal accidents looks statistically very questionable to me because there are (fortunately) so few of them. They tried to compensate by looking at data over a long time period but over that time so many other factors about cars and traffic accidents changed that throwing it all in one basket looks off. So the second study which also tries to consider accidents seems like the better quality study.

@Laurel: Thank you, this is a great find, in particular because it directly references the research mentioned in my question. Out of interest, how did you find this? Using Google Scholar, or did you use a different approach?

@Jake A Reddit post tipped me off that Levitt had published a study (and a TED talk), and that was easy enough to find with Google. Plugging the name of the study into Scholar allowed me to find articles that cited it.

This is a good answer but note that Levitt et al. are the only ones who have conducted an actual dummy test crash to directly compare seat belts vs child seats. Everyone else is just looking at the (noisy) data. There's a strong suspicion that such dummy tests have indeed been conducted but then not published because they've demonstrated the "wrong" result.

@JonathanReez I don't know where you're getting that idea from, but these seats are tested using dummies as part of their certification process. The idea that only one person has tested them, or that "they" are hiding the data is wrong.

@JackAidley yes they’re tested but were they ever tested in a direct comparison against seatbelts alone? That seems like the most obvious test to do and yet not a single such report has ever been published. Put 5 dummies in a car seat, then 5 in seat belts. Crash them. Give us the numbers. Levitt did this, no one else did (at least publicly).

Note that it's comparing child seats "when not misused" vs regular seat belts, but child seats are really easy to misuse. I currently have a child seat, but often need to take it out to fold the back seat down for cargo, or to for more people. I've lost count of the number of times I discovered that I had forgotten to clip it back in properly, or sometimes at all, which would lead to the entire seat flying out the window in an accident. My child is old enough that if it wasn't a legal and insurance requirement, I'd have ditched it for the regular belts long ago.

The "when not misused" caveat is so suspicious that it makes me wonder if this author's data also supports Levitt's conclusion. If safety seats were so beneficial, no caveat would be needed. I mean, table saws aren't dangerous if you follow all the instructions. Does that mean table saws aren't dangerous? (I don't think many people would misuse a safety seat on purpose)

I shall start by saying that this is a somewhat sensitive subject, as giving the wrong advice could have terrible consequences.  If you are reading this as a way to make a decision about how to transport your child(ren) then I would encourage you to have a look at the data.  Cars are really dangerous, and it seems there are things you can do to reduce the risk.  Do not listen to me, I do not have children or any professional experience in road safety.
In trying to answer this as data question I started with a 25 minute youtube video that introduces most of the papers referenced below.
It is easy to find correlation between injury and death rates and child seat use.  For example Elliott et al. 2006 found a relative risk for death of 0.72 (0.54-0.97 95% CI) associated with the use of a child restraint system in children of ages 2 to 6, and 0.79 (0.59-1.05) when excluding cases of serious misuse. This represents a 21% reduction in the chance of dying in an accident.  Arbogast et al. 2009 find reductions of adjusted relative risk for injury in children of ages 4 to 8 of 0.55 (0.32–0.96), representing a 45% reduction in risk.  This effect appears particularly pronounced in younger children, with Zaloshnja et al. 2007 finding a 81.8% lower chance of injury in children aged 2 to 3.
However this sort of study has been questioned in a number of ways.  Probably the hardest to deal with is the question of how much of this correlation represents the use of child restraint systems causally resulting in lower rates of death and injury of the individual, and how much this represents the use of child restraint systems serving as a marker for wealth, the use of safer cars and/or more responsible driving behaviour.  There are also questions about the validity of the data.  The presence of child restraint systems is easier to prove than the use or not of a seat belt, so it is postulated that when insurance professionals ask parents of  children who where unrestrained they may be incentivised to say they had a seat belt on.  This would inflate the rate of harm associated with seat belt only use.
One study that attempted to control for these variables is Levitt 2005 who finds that child safety seats are no better than seat belts at reducing fatalities among children aged 2-6.  Another is Anderson et al. 2009 that separates out booster seats and full seats with their own four point harness.  This finds the estimates for chance of dying actually higher for booster seats than just seat belts, though none of the differences are statistically significant (Table 3, Panel II).  Ma Et al. 2013 look specifically at booster seats compared to seat belts, and find significantly increased rates of some injuries, specifically "AIS > 0 injury to the neck and thorax".
It must be noted all these studies highlight the problem for incorrect installation of child safety seats as an unmodelled variable in the data, with the first two estimating this rate at 80% and >50% respectively.  The importance of properly fitted seats is illustrated by Ciccone et al. 1997 who find at 25 mph "For the properly restrained dummies, the safety seats provided excellent protection from the crash forces. For the improperly restrained dummies, protection ranged from adequate to nonexistent, depending on the type of misuse."  This could disguise a significant positive effect of properly installed seats.
On a similar vein Edgerton et al. looked at children between 20 and 40 lb in either a full child seat or booster seats and found odds ratios between 4.4 and 29 for various injury metrics.  They interpreted this as the harm from switching from full child seats to booster seats too early.
There are few crash tests that directly compare seat belts to child seats.  Kriston et al.  (which is not peer reviewed, but published by the US DoT) compared a booster seat to seat belts with and without belt guides with a crash test dummy "aged" approximately 12 years, and find the booster seat 33% better (16%-50%).  Talimian et al. 2023 do computer modelling and find a four point better that a three point, but their models do not look much like what I see sold as car seats.
Another point that is worth mentioning is the importance of position in the car on the chance of injury.  As I have mentioned on mechanics.SE Arbogast et al. 2008 found "children seated in the center rear have a 43% lower risk of injury compared with children in a rear outboard position".

Thanks, good answer. Also note that only Levitt et al. have conducted (or at least published) data from an actual dummy crash. Everyone else is just analyzing the (noisy) data.

@JonathanReez I thought about putting that in, but the way it is described does not sound to me like the way proper crash tests should be performed and reported in peer reviewed literature. "I conducted my own crash tests at an independent lab..."

Yeah but the weird part is that nobody else published actual crash data to show the contrary in the 20 years since. I’m 95% convinced it’s because the crash data has so far proven Levitt correct.

@JonathanReez "nobody else published actual crash data to show the contrary in the 20 years since" Are you sure? Google scholar finds lots of papers, but I feel in no position to summarise them.

Yes I’ve done lots of research into this and I’m highly confident it’s never been published, despite this being extremely valuable data for car seat companies. I think they’ve done the crash tests, didn’t like the data and just shoved it under a rug. Levitt et al. are of the same opinion.

@JonathanReez That's an interesting (and plausible) hypothesis. If trials were perfectly conclusive the debate would be settled by now, given the high stakes. It is a bit counter-intuitive to me though as somebody who traveled the U.S. with a child in a child seat (starting at age 1 and then annually). Intuitively a child seat appears to provide "infinitely" better protection than booster+belt, which in turn is "infinitely" safer than nothing. But indeed, like with condoms, the weak spot may be proper installation and handling. Handled properly, protection is good :-).

@Peter-ReinstateMonica: Your first "infinitely better" is unjustifiable. The seatbelt mechanism is different from the child seat restraining mechanism, and what you want to minimize is maximum deceleration and not speed.

@user21820 Well, car seats have (iirc) two shoulder straps and provide stability to the side; the child seems much better protected. Additionally, adult belts fit worse on a small-ish child, even with booster. It seems a lot must happen before a child in a properly installed car seat gets hurt.

@user21820 I'm also a big fan of backward installation; given that most impacts occur forward, that should protect much better.

Re. Peter and @user21820 Do note Edgerton et al. is doing the exact comparison you are talking about, and had by far the largest effect size.  Odds ratio of 29 is 29 times more likely to suffer chest injuries in a booster seat than a 4 point car seat.  That is not infinite but it is quite a lot. That is specifically forward facing seats, backward may be even better.  It is quite young children though.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica I suspect that past a certain age the child seats are merely providing the illusion of extra safety. Also note that car seat mandates have so far prevented 100x more births than child lives saved (see: Car seats as contraception).

That paper looks at the marginal impact on families, so it already takes that into account. Since car seat mandates were introduced in different years in different states, we can calculate the marginal impact on fertility. And then it turns out that 100x kids were not born compared to number of kids saved.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica: Your first comment does absolutely nothing to address my point regarding maximum deceleration not speed. Think. How do shoulder straps reduce maximum deceleration? Especially if they are secure, then not at all. Use mathematics rather than intuition.

@User65535: Thanks for your comment, but observe that I did not make any claim except "Peter's claim is unjustifiable.". I do not have enough data to conclude with satisfactory confidence about which is better.

@user21820 I'm not passionate about it but typically, slack increases both speed and max acceleration because you have a period of no acceleration (or deceleration, if you want) at all for the body while the car is violently decelerated, until you smash into the belt(s) which, in the case of a regular seat belt, has an elasticity coefficient designed for an adult body and is too stiff for a small child, and therefore accelerates the little body more violently than it would an adult one which would stretch it more. Starting deceleration early spreads it out over more time.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica there’s probably a Goldilocks zone where seat belts are too stiff but a car seat has just enough slack. Anything less and the seat belt works fine. Anything more and nothing will help you. I suspect that zone is so narrow that in practice the benefits are slim for older kids.

@JonathanReez I fail to see how any slack could be good, from first principles as described.

https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamapediatrics/fullarticle/569418 seems to be missing although it was among the first ones to show up for a quick search.

@Gábor Thanks, added.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica: I will repeat myself once more. Use mathematics rather than intuition. If the child seat has two shoulder straps and they are completely secure, then upon impact the neck will snap forward relative to the body with exactly the same acceleration as the car's deceleration. If a booster seat is used with a normal seat belt, it is NOT clear that there will be the same neck snap. And your statement "Starting deceleration early spreads it out over more time" is yet another bogus statement; the deceleration is not constant.

@user21820 How is the "spreading out" argument bogus? You have to get from v1 to v2; the more time you have available doing that, the better. If you don't decelerate for an initial period of time you have less time available, leading (with mathematical certainty) to a higher average acceleration. Slamming into the seat belt which already has decelerated during that time and will now make the body catch up very quickly before both (belt and body) continue to follow the car's remaining deceleration looks like a bad peak to me as well. That's why modern belts have pre-tensioners.

@user21820 To sum up, elasticity smooths peaks; slack does not.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica: You are making the totally bogus assumption that the deceleration is spread out. You didn't even bother to read what I wrote, namely: "If the child seat ... completely secure ... snap forward ... same acceleration ...". If you refuse to do a fair comparison between child seat and booster seat plus seat belt, then stop making totally unjustified claims.

@user21820 Because there is more time, it is necessarily more spread out. That is the meaning of "spread out". Any sudden acceleration that happens in this first interval is in store when the body hits the seat belt in the slack scenario, plus the accumulated rest of the deceleration in that interval, unless the belt with slack is more elastic (but we are talking about equal belts in the principle discussion about slack, or even less elastic belts in the specific comparison of child seat without slack vs. adult belt with slack).

@user21820 My specific suspicion here is that (1) the seats are often installed with too much slack (I was at an installation training; you have to press it hard into the cushion and really tighten the holding seat belt); and (2) the children aren't strapped in tightly enough, perhaps because they complain or because of ignorance or convenience). Slack is bad.

@‍Peter: You still do not think through what I wrote. You still claim unjustifiably that deceleration is necessarily spread out over the same time interval. I give up. No mathematics, no proper analysis.

If a causal intervention is correlated with another variable (e.g. the use of child restraint systems serving as a marker for wealth) and you "control" for that other variable by crudely regressing it away, you are incorrectly removing the variance driven by the causal intervention. This analysis would lead to Type II error (false negatives).

I've awarded you the bounty. Thanks for finding "Kriston et al." => its so suspicious that they've tested a 12-year old dummy rather than using a much more obvious 4-year old one to test out the car seats effectiveness hypothesis. Makes me even more confident that all such crash data is shoved under a rug due to not being convincing enough. Booster seats for 2+ year olds make sense, car seats probably do not.

@JonathanReez Thanks.  I have been wondering what is the technical reason they cannot build a car seat that only takes up the space of an adult, they could be really expensive and still loads cheaper than buying and running a bigger car.
